# how do I create skin file to use in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I've been looking for the skinpacker from the libgdx SVN without success. 
and then I learn it's no longer exist. SO, the question is how do I create a skin.json file to use in my libgdx project. Do you know any tools that allow me to work with GUI to create a skin. 
THank you.

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/extensions

Comment: I already search the gdx-tools packet but cannot find the skinpacker within it. can you point me out a little bit more specific .Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As [Gnurfos says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13620897/4794), you need to run `TexturePacker2` to generate the skin files. I found it helpful to set up a [helper class](https://github.com/donkirkby/vograbulary/blob/22eb206cddab4e3685536f65aeeaf6e3a813920a/vograbulary-test/src/com/github/donkirkby/vograbulary/AssetPacker.java) so I don't have to remember all the path information.

```
public class AssetPacker {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TexturePacker2.process(
                "assets-raw/skin", 
                "../vograbulary-android/assets/data/ui", 
                "uiskin.atlas");
    }
}
```

Here are some related notes from my project's [README file](https://github.com/donkirkby/vograbulary/blob/22eb206cddab4e3685536f65aeeaf6e3a813920a/README.md#contributing).

> To edit the graphics files, edit the contents of vograbulary-test/assets-raw, and then run vograbulary-test/src/com.github.donkirkby.vograbulary.AssetPacker. To change the font, follow the instructions for running Hiero. Launch Hiero, open the vograbulary-test/assets-raw/default.hiero settings file, and then save the font file over vograbulary-android/assets/data/ui/default.fnt. That will also generate default.png, which you need to move back to vograbulary-test/assets-raw/skin/default.png. Finally, run the AssetPacker again.

The original creation of the skin is described in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18526116/4794).

Answer (score 1):

With the latest versions, you don't need the SkinPacker.jar anymore.

Here's how I do it:

```
CLASSPATH=$LIB_DIR/gdx-tools.jar:$LIB_DIR/gdx.jar
CLASSNAME=com.badlogic.gdx.tools.imagepacker.TexturePacker2
INPUTDIR=uiskin_elements
OUTPUTDIR=.
java -classpath $CLASSPATH $CLASSNAME $INPUTDIR $OUTPUTDIR uiskin.atlas
```

This generates a uiskin.atlas and uiskin.png, assuming you put all .png in a directory called uiskin_elements.