# Using scene2d.ui with libgdx: where does the skin come from?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d

I've read about libgdx's [scene2d features](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2d), including the UI elements, but I can't get them to work. They all seem to use a skin object, how do I create one?

I've gone through the [nice tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SimpleApp) that creates a simple libgdx game catching raindrops in a bucket, and I've created a simple board game app by loading images with a [texture atlas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18525416/4794). However, scene2d sounds like a better way to control the moving pieces in a board game app, as well as any buttons and menus.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To load a skin, you can start with the sample skin files used in the libgdx test project.

1. [Atlaspack File](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data/uiskin.atlas)
2. [Json File](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data/uiskin.json)
3. [Atlaspack Image](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data/uiskin.png)
4. [Font File](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data/default.fnt)

There's a bit more detail in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16182844/4794), and I found that I had to move the files into a subdirectory of assets to avoid a bug in the HTML version. (If I leave files in the assets folder, I see an error message like, "GwtApplication: exception: Error reading file data/uiskin.json.")

I posted a [complete example](https://github.com/donkirkby/vograbulary/tree/scene2d-demo) that displays a single button, and the interesting code is all in the [game class](https://github.com/donkirkby/vograbulary/blob/scene2d-demo/vograbulary/src/com/github/donkirkby/vograbulary/VograbularyGame.java). The example is so simple that you only need two member variables to hold the scene and the button.

```
private Stage stage;
private TextButton button;
```

To create the skin, you just load the data file.

```
Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json"));
```

Wire the button into the stage.

```
stage = new Stage();
button = new TextButton("Click Me!", skin);
stage.addActor(button);
```

Wire a listener into the button, and register the stage to receive events.

```
button.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        button.setText("Clicked!");
    }
});
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

The `render()` method is basically a call to `stage.draw()`.

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

stage.act(Math.min(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 1 / 30f));
stage.draw();
```

Then you just need to layout the screen when it resizes.

```
button.setPosition(
        (width-button.getWidth())/2, 
        (height-button.getHeight())/2);
```

If your screen is more complicated, consider using a [Table](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2dui#Table).

If you want to use a different font, you can generate the font file and image file using [Hiero](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Hiero). After you've done that, you'll have to take the new font image and use the [TexturePacker](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer) to repack it with the other [skin assets](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets-raw/skin).

Answer (score 1):

Now Libgdx provide Git repository to get skin, you can download it from: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-skins, copy assets:https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-skins/tree/master/skins/visui/assets to your project